# How to force Inno Setup to set the installation folder dynamically

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I am creating an installation package and user should be able to install it on a specific location only.

In order to do so I read some registry values in the `[Code]` section to determine the installation path.

Having the installation path I need to force Inno Setup to set the installation folder to a specific location at run-time.

Is this possible in Inno Setup? Which section of script should be used if so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Use a [scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants) to set the default installation path;
- Use the [`DisableDirPage` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_disabledirpage) to prevent a user from modifying it.

```
[Setup]
DefaultDirName={code:GetDefaultDirName}
DisableDirPage=Yes
```

```pascal
[Code]

function GetDefaultDirName(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := ...;
end;
```

*Note that the `DefaultDirName` is resolved (and hence the `GetDefaultDirName` is called) after [`InitializeSetup`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeSetup) and before [`InitializeWizard`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeWizard). So you can use `InitializeSetup` for any setup you might need to resolve the installation folder.*